# automatic load-balancing of threads in python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I have many independent tasks with different runtime and I wan them to finish as soon as possible. So I need run the task with longer runtime first. Also to make full use of the multiple CPU and multiple Cores, I need evenly distribute the tasks. Note I am only working on a single machine instead of multiple machines.

Here my question is: can subprocess module in python do this job? if not, is there other module in python doing a better job in this case?

Thanks

Derek